# I am facing a challenge with julia range

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia.
While trying out examples online, I got to the plot below:

```
using Plots

# 10 data points in 4 series
xs = range(0, 2π, length = 10)
data = [sin.(xs) cos.(xs) 2sin.(xs) 2cos.(xs)]

# We put labels in a row vector: applies to each series
labels = ["Apples" "Oranges" "Hats" "Shoes"]

# Marker shapes in a column vector: applies to data points
markershapes = [:circle, :star5]

# Marker colors in a matrix: applies to series and data points
markercolors = [
    :green :orange :black :purple
    :red   :yellow :brown :white
]

plot(
    xs,
    data,
    label = labels,
    shape = markershapes,
    color = markercolors,
    markersize = 10
)
```

The Problem I am facing is at the beginning. Even if I try below alone on `REPL`

```
julia> xs = range(0, 2π, length = 10)
```

I receive the error below:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching range(::Int64, ::Float64; length=10)
Closest candidates are:
  range(::Any; length, stop, step) at range.jl:76
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Did I forget to include some Package?

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of Julia. If you can, you should use the latest stable version of Julia (v1.6.0 at time of writing), for which `xs = range(0, 2π, length = 10)` just works! (And it's got many other improvements, too, like time to plot things!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of Julia are you using? It sounds like you are using a version that is older than the tutorial you are reading. I can verify that `range(0, 2π, length = 10)` yields `0.0:0.6981317007977318:6.283185307179586` on Julia 1.5 and Julia 1.6, even without specifying `stop`

Comment: You were completely right.. I just installed 1.5 and it works as per the example. I always tend to install versions available in my OS packaging system, to avoid any dependency problems...

Comment: the keyword argument `length` is compulsory, unlike in the deprecated `linspace`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I should have made more research before posting. it's an error in the original post I guess.

I should have used:

```
julia> xs = range(0, stop=2π, length = 10)
0.0:0.6981317007977318:6.283185307179586
```

No more errors!!

It's weird, I am following official tutorial... :((

Comment: Please post a link to the official tutorial you are following as well as the version of Julia you are running. It may just be a version mismatch, but if not then I can file an issue.

Comment: it was a version problem.. it's all clear now to me. Thank you .

Comment: No worries. Just FYI pretty much all the standard repositories tend to lag *way* behind the stable releases you get from the Julia webpage.